# Delete answers not visible; neither is their delete vote

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Since I have > 10k rep I can vote to delete questions.

I have noticed several time on page https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days that some delete votes click through to *answers* not *questions*, and over there nothing about deletion is visible.

Currently in view:

[image]

That top one links to answer https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/120063/8036, but I see no delete votes there (as they would appear under a question), and I think I have also never seen the possibility to add a delete vote with one of these *answers* (yes, I'm aware of the delay period of 2 days after closure):

[image]

What am I missing here?

- Does voting to delete answers require more rep?
- Does that top answer currently have 1 or 2 delete votes?
- What is the significance of the smaller font - does that indicate an answer?

Comment: I currently see "delete (2)" under that answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Interesting - I still don't. Your rep is 228k+ ;-)

Comment: Unable to check, now that such answer has positive score...

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the 10k tools were broken; those haven't been touched in... well years at this point.

Answer (score 4):

You need 10k rep to delete questions but 20k to delete answers.  However, there's only one "delete votes" page where you're seeing this, and it's computed for the site, not for individual users.  Unfortunately that means that, yes, you'll see some things there that you can't vote on.

The larger font size is for questions and the smaller font size is for answers.  The number to the left of the link is the number of votes that have already been cast. I *think* the number in parentheses to the right is the number of additional votes needed, but I'm not sure.  (While it usually takes three votes and you'd think you could derive the one from the other, it takes more votes to delete a highly-upvoted question.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does voting to delete answers require more rep?

[From 20k reputation privileges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (emphasis mine):

> What are trusted users?
> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - **Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower**
> - Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
> - Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

The other two questions you have I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thanks, I was unable to find that page. Bookmarking https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges now ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen you can get there via the help center, which you can access via the top right icon in the nav bar - the "Privileges" section is at the bottom of the center column of links. Though it's not straightforward as I'm pretty sure I searched for it when I found the link to quote :)