# Delete votes but no delete option

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderator-tools

The on-hold question [Can anyone solve these acronyms?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123538/can-anyone-solve-these-acronyms) appears in my moderator tools *Delete votes* panel/queue, but when I click on it it has no *delete* option (and it is not deleted yet). When writing this it was asked and put on hold 'yesterday'.

What is the matter?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You currently have a reputation of 11,555.

[10k moderator tools](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion.

(This is lifted for [20k users](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).

The question was close yesterday, hence you can't vote to delete yet.

Comment: Confirmed after waiting another day, thanks. [Another example](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5590/delete-answers-not-visible-neither-is-their-delete-vote) of the tools page not being up to the usual SE standards ;-)